# What is Google Maps Platform Transition Account

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am using google maps api and I came to know about Google Maps Platform Transition Account where google gives one time credit to users so I wanted to know how can i get access to this credit so that i could use these credits for development and later enable billing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Google Maps Platform FAQ

> The "Google Maps Platform Transition Account" was created to help certain customers transition to our new pay-as-you-go pricing plan. **This transition account enabled Google to provide these customers with a one-time credit, so that they could continue using Google Maps Platform up to the limit of the $200 free tier.** Once this limit is exceeded, the billing account will shut down and you will lose access to the service. To avoid service interruptions, we urge you to set your own billing account, and continue to enjoy the $200 monthly free tier.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#transition_account

So, once you have gotten a transition account you have a possibility to use requests within the free tier of $200. You shouldn't request any additional credit. To my knowledge these transition accounts were created for users who had Google Cloud projects prior to migration to Google Maps platform in July 2018. I'm not sure that these transition accounts are created for new projects created after July 2018.

You can consider an option to get a Google Cloud Platform $300 credit. I think it should be applicable to Google Maps APIs as well

Have a look at 
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

I hope this clarifies your doubts.